# Tangentplane of a hyperboloid

Tags: multivariable-calculus, 3d

I have a hyperboloid $H$, which is $x^2+\frac{y^2}{4}-z^2=1$.

I want to show that all points $P$ on $H$, in which the tangentplane to $H$ that goes through the point $(1,4,2)$, all are in a plane. And thereafter also determine the equation of this plane.

How would I go by doing this. I'm unsure where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P(X,Y,Z)$.

Thus, the equation of our tangent plane it's:
$$2X(x-X)+\frac{Y}{2}(y-Y)-2Z(z-Z)=0$$ or
$$Xx+\frac{Y}{4}y-Zz-X^2-\frac{Y^2}{4}+Z^2=0$$ or
since $(X,Y,Z)$ placed on our hyperboloid, we obtain
$$Xx+\frac{Y}{4}y-Zz-1=0.$$
But $(1,4,2)$ placed on this plane, which gives
$$X+Y-2Z-1=0,$$
which is an equation of the plane: $x+y-2z-1=0$.